# Sending a variable as part of request object instead of form fields in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I acknowledge, I am very much a beginner in JSP as I come from JavaScript background.

But as I understand things,

**when you hit a submit in a JSP form, request object gets passed to the action path with the form fields.**

```
<form name="loginForm" method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="<%=(request.getContextPath())%>/Login.do" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm()">
    .......
    .......
    <tr id="userNameRow">
        <th id="usernameLabel">Username</th>
        <td align="left">
            <input name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" type="text" aria-describedby="loginError"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="userPwdRow">
        <th id="passwordLabel">Password</th>
        <td align="left">
            <input name="password" id="password" onKeyPress="decodeKeyPress(event)" autocomplete="off" type="password"></td>
    </tr>
```

**What I want is, instead of what is typed on the pwd field, I want to store it in a variable and replace the text in pwd field.**

I thought to have `keypress` event on the field, so that I can look for the keyCode and eventually reset the field value.

```
var pwdString = "";
function decodeKeyPress(event) {
    var xCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
    pwdString += String.fromCharCode(xCode);
    console.log("My Key Press Code ---"+xCode);
    var input = document.querySelector("input#password");
    input.select();
    input.value="";
}
```

Now, onSubmit instead of the pwd field value(which is reset to empty string), I want to pass the variable `pwdString` value as part of the request object.

So that in other page I can read it as

```
String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
```

How to do it in JSP ?

Comment: use a hidden property and set the pwd value to it in js and then submit the form.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Thanks for the input. I am pretty much a beginner in JSP, can you show how to achieve the same?

Comment: declare a hidden property with an id `<input type="hidden" id="someId"/>` and using `JS` access this property to set value from pwd. But go a head with @Ullas Hunka 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of password field you can use the following:

```
var pwdField = document.getElementById("password");
var pwdString;
pwdField.onChange(function(){//You can use keypress or keyup here
  pwdString = pwdField.value;
});
```

For submision, you can use ajax instead of the form. The example is as follows:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/Login.do", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("fname=Henry&password="+pwdString);
```

and then in java, you can use `String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");`

**Note:** Sending the password as the string is vulnerable and has no security as JavaScript can be accessed anytime from the DevTool. So try not using it.

Comment: I understand and appreciate the efforts for the answer. I will keep this in mind going forward. But can I do something with the current form submit without going the AJAX way.

Comment: As far I know there are only three ways of communicating with server, socket, ajax and direct submission of the form.